# When pressing F1 hotkey in SQL Server 2008 R2 hang my Maganement Studio?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, chm

Sometimes I miss the 1 or the F2 in my computer keyboard when using SQL Server Maganement Studio, that causes my SQL MS to hang and the I have to close it with the Task Manager, but many time I loss a lot from the queries I was working on, so I would like to fix this problem, 
Maybe someone here has the same problem.

```
Microsoft Document Explorer
The Application Data folder for Microsoft Document Explorer could not be created
```

[image: Error Message]

[image: Error Message at Desktop clock corner]

Comment: Haven't come across that. I'd probably use process monitor to see what folder it is trying to create and why it fails (e.g. invalid path or access denied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many intents to solve this problem, I received this message:

> External help is not available because Microsoft Document Explorer is
>   not installed. To view help, change your Help preferences to use the
>   Integrated Help Viewer or Install Microsoft Document Explorer

I tried to do it at Tools->Options->Help->General->

Show Help usaing: Integrated Help Viewer

Search Result per page: 20

Show Topic abstracts: checked

Reuse Topic window: checked

Highlight search termn: checked

I had to tried many times until SSMS wanted let me to do it.

Now the problem has been partially solved, when I press F1 the SSMS does not hang, but when I still try to change something in the help options, then chunks..

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the SSMS program (in the start menu / desktop) and select "run as administrator". Do whatever you do to cause SSMS to hang, quit and re-run as normal user. This should remove that warning.